# Difference between 2 dates showing wrong result

Tags: c#

I'm trying to build a project and trying to compare between two dates from the **date time picker**.

Let's say it's departure and arrival time. The user chooses the date 5/11/2016 on departure and 6/11/2016 on arrival.

The code is below:

```
DateTime departure = dtpDeparture.Value.Date;
DateTime arrival = dtpArrival.Value.Date;

MessageBox.Show(departure- arrival).Days.ToString();
```

The result is: 6576 which is wrong.. it should be 1 (the difference is one day only)?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: And you are sure it isn't showing `6.576`, which can be correct if the time is taken into account.

Comment: What does `MessageBox.Show(departure.ToString() + " - " + arrival.ToString())` show?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I don't think so since I put .Value.Date so time shouldn't be taken into account.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you have with this code.

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue, double check your arrival and departure times, they are most likely the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't the time be arrival - departure if it is the same flight.

Comment: Voting to close. The code you posted cannot compile.

Comment: How did you get 6576 when your messagebox wont even work? it should be ` MessageBox.Show((arrival - departure).Days.ToString());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(departure - arrival).TotalDays` has always worked for me. Make sure your date format is correct too, you might be checking from May 11th to June 11th.

Comment: I changed the format of the date picker to dd/MM/yyyy as well and it still shows the same result.

Comment: Using `TotalDays` is indeed the correct approach. But it should always be greater or equal to `Days`. And the problem is that the `Days` is already too large.

Comment: Thank you. That function is correct. I restarted my visual studio and it worked. This has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [DateTime.Subtract()]
Please find the link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby(v=vs.110).aspx)